# Everything between "[reply]" and extract the reply number

Tags: php, regex, extract, text-extraction

Please take a look at the following situation below.

```
[reply="292"] Text Here [/reply]
```

What I am trying to get is the number between the quotations in `reply="NUMBERS"`. I want to extract that to one variable and the text between `[reply="NUMBER"] this text here [/reply]` to another variable.

So for this example:

```
[reply="292"] Text Here [/reply]
```

I want to extract the reply number: `292` and the text between the `reply` tags: `Text here`.

I have tried this:

```
\[reply\=\"]([A-Z]\w)\[\/reply]
```

But this only works until the `reply` tag, doesn't work after that. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: This website is not / should not be a personal regex generator.

Comment: Also, impersonating people is not cool / may be illegal in your jurisdiction.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What are you talking about?

Comment: Are you the real Taylor Swift? The celebrity

Comment: @TaylorSwift: Good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I left generic (. *), but you can specify a type like decimal (\d+).

php:

```
$s = '[reply="292"] Text Here [/reply]';
$expr = '/\[reply=\"(.*)\"\](.*)\[\/reply\]/';
if(preg_match($expr,$s,$r)){
    var_dump($r);
}
```

javascript:

```
s = '[reply="292"] Text Here [/reply]'
s.match(/\[reply=\"(.*)\"\](.*)\[\/reply\]/)
//["[reply="292"] Text Here [/reply]", "292", " Text Here "]
```

Comment: Thanks, works with numbers, letters and pretty much everything.

Answer (score 1):

Easy!

```
\[reply\=\"(\d+)\"](.*?)\[\/reply]
```

### Explanation

1. `\d` for digit
2. `+` for 1 or more occurrence of the specified character.
3. `[\w\s]` for any character in word and whitespace (`\s`)

Then apply it to PHP like this:

```
<?php                                                                       
  $str = "[reply=\"292\"] Text Here [/reply]";
  preg_match('/\[reply\=\"(\d+)\"]([\w\s]+)\[\/reply]/', $str, $re);
  print_r($re[1]); // printing group 1, the reply number
  print_r($re[2]); // printing group 2, the text
?>
```

### Important!!

Just get the group value, not all. You only need some of it anyway.

Comment: Hi thanks. Sorry it may have been confusing but it does not work with anything else other than number and letters (the text).

Comment: Sorry, I made iterate update to my answer every time I answer in StackOverflow. Please review the latest update. I am sure it's perfect

Comment: Unfortunately, it still does not work with anything other than letters and numbers

Comment: I thought it is meant that way. That's why I do so. I can make it match everything. Never mind